# heroku error during build app[web.1]: sh: 1: if-env: not found

Tags: macos, heroku

Deploying a react app to Heroku and kept getting this error when I ran
I tried to uninstall and install packages

to see my heroku errors I ran `heroku logs --tail`

````
2021-09-28T10:43:17.942929+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-09-28T10:43:17.946623+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: if-env: not found```
````

Answer (score 0):

if-env needs to be listed in package.json

`npm i if-env`